# Cannot find my WiFi router

Tags: wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 along with Windows 7 OS.
After installation, I can see other WiFi connections/router, but I can't see my WiFi router.

My WiFi router is named 'iball baton' with model no. `iB-WRX300NP`.
What should I do to find my WiFi connection?
Please assist.

Comment: Do you see your network in Win7?

Comment: Please paste the output of `lshw -C network`

Comment: Yes I can see my network in Windows 7. - @GabrielaGarcia

Comment: Output of command:<code>$ sudo lshw -C network<code> :
 <code>description:Wireless interface
 product:Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
  vendor:Intel Corporation
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@0000:12:00.0
  logical name:wlp18s0
  version: 00
  serial: 8c:a9:82:09:41:64<code>.......
  <code>description:Ethernet interface
  product:RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
  vendor:Realtek Semiconductor Co. Ltd.
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@0000:13:00.0
       logical name:enp19s0
       version: 02
       serial: f0:4d:a2:be:7e:c3<code> - @Kulfy